# How do you go throught a Java list, and check if it equals multiple strings?

Tags: java

I do not know if this is possible, but if it is would it be done like this?:

```
List<String> arrayList= new ArrayList<String>();
arrayList.add("ex1");
arrayList.add("ex2");
arrayList.add("ex12");

for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++) {
    switch (arrayList.get(i)) {
        case "ex1":
           //Do something
        default:
           //Do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: It's possible since Java 7. But change your condition to i < arrayList.length.

Comment: @Eran AFAIK Java doesn't let you overload `[]` operator in classes

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I missed that part. I was referring to switch with Strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java 7, you can do:

```
List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
arrayList.add("ex1");
arrayList.add("ex2");
arrayList.add("ex12");

for (String element : arrayList) {
    switch (element) {
    case "ex1":
        // Do something
        break;
    default:
        // Do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, in Java 6 you can do this to ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer sorry, I though `switch` supports `String` since Java 7.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza 1- The OP is already using `switch` with `String`, but the `for-each` statement was introduced in Java 6, my bad for not been specific :P

Answer (score 1):

A `ArrayList` is an implementation of `List` which is backed by an array, so you need to use the `List` API to retrieve values, for example...

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
    switch (arrayList.get(i)) {
        case "ex1":
        'Do something'
        default:
        'Do something else'
    }
}
```

You could also use a `for-each` loop...

```
for (String value : arrayList) {
    switch (value) {
        case "ex1":
        'Do something'
        default:
        'Do something else'
    }
}
```

Take a look at [The Collections Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/), [`java.util.List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and [`java.util.ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for more details

You also might like to have a look at [The `for` Statement trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Comment: `arrayList.length()` should be `arrayList.size()` :)